# What am I missing to decode a JSON bool using JSONKit for IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, deserialization

I have a REST endpoint that returns a BOOL value depending on whether or not the server operation was successful.  It returns the response body as simply `true` or `false`

When I try to decode the value from the server, I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.
```

I have gone so far as to remove the server response the equation. Now I am just trying to get this code to work:

```
NSString *result = @"true";
NSNumber *response = [ result objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone error:&err ];
if( response == NULL )
    NSLog(@"error: %@", err.localizedDescription );
else
    NSLog( @"%d", ( int )response );
```

No matter what, I still run into my error condition and print out the error message:

```
Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: it isn't a json response if the entire body consists of 'true' or 'false'. try returning {"response": true }

Comment: I was under the impression because the documentation for JSONKit says it will translation "true" to an NSNumber and the error says it expects the token `true`.  I thought it might not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"true"` isnt a valid json string

Comment: It may not be valid JSON, but I thought the JSONKit framework would still parse it correctly, from it's documentation.  Apparently I was wrong.  Returning the result `{ "data": true }` resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You set your `result` to the `NSString` `@"true"`, which is not JSON.

Rather you should get a `NSString *response` from the server and then apply `objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:error:` to it.

To check valid JSON, try http://jsonlint.com/.